# kvm_open: cannot open /proc

Tags: freebsd, out-of-memory, load-average

I have 100+ boxes running FreeBSD 8.4 amd64 RELEASE (p9) with the same configuration.

And only one of them sometimes behaves strangely: load average (generally 4~6, it's ok course box have 8 CPU cores) grows up to 30-40, system running slow and `top` starts to print `kvm_open: cannot open /proc/[some_numbers]/mem` messages. When load average goes down, such messages not appears anymore.

The question is not how to fight with high la, but what does `kvm_open: cannot open /proc` mean? System does not running out of memory, as I see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's caused by the process exiting between top getting the process list and top trying to get info on that particular process. It's more common on a very busy box but generally safe to ignore. You might consider it a bug, you might not.